# port mirroring timestamp

Tags: wireshark, timestamp

I have enabled port mirroring of a specific port on my switch. The mirrored packets are from my eNodeB. I am viewing the mirrored packets on another server using wireshark. So where are the timestamps on the packets seen on wireshark taken from? Is it the time stamp of the server or the eNodeB?

Answer (score 0):

the server. wireshark runs locally. if you are remoting to the server and running wireshark there than it's the server's timestamps.

Comment: Thank you Tatsu. Yes I am analysing the packets on wireshark on the server.

Comment: welcome if this is it then please upvote and mark as solution. thanks :-)